# Why Tomcat7 always complain about older version APR 1.1.20?

Tags: tomcat, apr

I have installed Tomcat 7.0.22 on Windows, put in lib tcnative_1.dll. Its version 1.2.22.
But when I start tomcat - always this complain.
Why?

> 26-Oct-2011 18:49:25 org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener
>   init INFO: An older version 1.1.20 of the APR based Apache Tomcat
>   Native library is installed, while Tomcat recommends a minimum version
>   of 1.1.22

Comment: copy paste the error message and any other relevant information

Comment: 26-Oct-2011 18:49:25 org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: An older version 1.1.20 of the APR based Apache Tomcat Native library is installed, while Tomcat recommends a minimum version of 1.1.22